# Given $\beta'' = k_1 ((N \circ \beta) $x$ \beta ') + k_2(N \circ \beta)$, proof $k = \sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Given parameterized curve with lenght arc length 1 $\beta: I \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^3$ in a surface $M$. Let $N$ denote a normal vectorfield on $M$.
First we want to prove the existance of two functions $k1,k2:I\rightarrow\mathbf{R}$ such that
$\beta''  = k_1 (N \circ \beta) $x$ \beta ' + k_2(N \circ \beta)$ and that $k = \sqrt{k_1^2+k_2^2}$, with $k$ the curvature of $\beta$.

I wanted to try this on one hand by orthonormal expansion in the basis $N,B,T$.
This gave:
$$\beta = (\beta N)N + (\beta T)T + (\beta B) B$$

We can prove that $\beta T$ is zero. But then I got stuck there.
Another important thing seems to be that we know that
$\beta'(N\circ\beta) = 0$. But I don't know how to use this combined. Can anybody help me finish this?

Comment: This is just incorrect. The equation should express $\beta''$ as a linear combination of $N$ and $N\times\beta'$.

Comment: Yes indeed, I corrected my question.

Comment: The point is that $\beta’’\cdot T=0$ and $N$ and $N\times T$ give a basis for the plane orthogonal to $T$.

Comment: And how do you prove this further? Do you have to multiply both sides and see which parts stay?